# mongoid splits nested attributes in two hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I've got a model `List` with nested attributes from another one, `Article`. What bugs me is I have Ruby request params having my first nested attribute in `Article` hash, and all the others(2nd,3rd article data, etc) in article_parameters.

I follow the standard mongoid tutorial here.

I have @list.articles.build in create method of List controller.
Can I influence what goes into build method? I've tried to call `build(all_the_correct_hashes)` but it does not seem to fix the issue.

So, in the nutshell I have 2 questions.

1. why `articles` gets only the first nested attribute, 2nd and next go to `article_parameters` hash?
2. why list.articles.build only creates _id in my Mongo document, but does not populate it with other fields?

Comment: Hard to say what's exactly being asked here. Post relevant code (with data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll write up my solution, since I see people upvoting my question.

Frankly, I did not find any answer as to why such behaviour occurs.
The solution is a bit hackish.

In your save controller, call `List.article.build(id => params[:id], someotherstuff => params[:someotherstuff])`

Everything you pass to build in this case will populate `article_parameters` hash.

`id` and `sometherstuff` are fields of my `Article` model.

I feel this should be done implicitly by Mongoid, but it just does not work. Their development does not see anything wrong with it, either.